# Spelunky vs Spelunky HD

Tags: discussion, tags

Let me start by saying I know very little about the differences between Spelunky and Spelunky HD. However, I assume there are some because a good number of the existing questions for it are also tagged [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) or [xbox-live-arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live-arcade), presumably to distinguish it as the HD version. This probably wasn't a good system in the first place, but now that the HD version has come to PC, it makes even less sense.

What needs to be done with these? Should we just remove the extraneous tags, or do we need a new tag for [spelunky-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelunky-hd)?

Comment: Per previous discussions on the subject, the key question here is: Is the existing content from the original **Spelunky** *materially different* in **Spelunky HD**? Or is the HD edition merely different because of the inclusion of new, *additional* content? If the former, we need a second tag. If the latter, then [tag:spelunky] should be plenty, and people can distinguish in the question body.

Comment: To address how different they are for folks who are not familiar with the game, [I'll point to a pair of chat messages I spoke of the subject in the past](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8738735#8738735).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lack of anyone else more knowledgeable speaking up, and based on the fact that from @GraceNote's link it appears as if there were enough differences to at least warrant the extra [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) tag, I propose the creation of [spelunky-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelunky-hd).

Worst case scenario, we collapse the tags together later.

Comment: +1, this is probably the best way to approach it.  I feel like we should do the same thing for [tag:ducktales-remastered] when ti comes out.

Comment: @gnomeslice Ducktales is a whole other ball of wax; it needs it's own tag, but for different reasons.

Comment: I've now implemented this and retagged the relevant questions as [tag:spelunky-hd]. As I said, it does not preclude the option of still merging the two tags together if we deem it appropriate, but it seems like a good first step.